# cin as istream object without stream buffer object's reference

Tags: c++, io

I was working on a question to pass `cin` as an argument, here is my code:

```
#include<istream>
#include<iostream>

void fun(std::istream &os)
{
    int i;
    os>>i;
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    fun(std::istream::cin);  //ERROR

    return 0;
}
```

The error says:

> ‘cin’ is not a member of ‘std::istream’ {aka ‘std::basic_istream’}

The error went away when it was made just `std::cin` - now it is written in book (CPP Primer) that `cin` is a `istream` object but the constructor for `istream` requires a reference to stream buffer object in order to be constructed. So how does `cin` just works without any argument? example:

`cin>>input;`

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin` is an object whose **type** is `std::istream`. Its name is `std::cin`. It's not a member of `std::istream`, so you can't name it as if it were. That's why the compiler complains about `std::istream::cin`.